# Simplest way to retrieve an int from a mongo result?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm pulling an int from a mongo cursor object like so:

```
DBObject mapObj = cursor.next();
int autostart = (int) (double) (Double) mapObj.get("autostart");
```

It seems strange that I have to triple cast to get it to an integer, is there a better way?

Comment: Just to clarify, autostart represents an integer value, not floating point. Whether I do it here or elsewhere, eventually the number that comes back from Mongo will eventually be used as an int.

Answer (score 17):

I think what you are really looking for is something like this:

```
DBObject mapObj = cursor.next();
int autostart = ((Number) mapObj.get("autostart")).intValue();
```

No conversion to a string and it is safe if the value gets converted to a Double or Long (with the potential loss of precision) from the original Integer value.  Double, Long and Integer all extend Number.

HTH Rob

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can do it this way:

`int autostart = Integer.valueOf(mapObj.get("autostart").toString());`

Regarding your last comment:

If you want double, use this:

`int autostart = Double.valueOf(mapObj.get("autostart").toString());`

But what is the sense in that? You could rather have :

`double autostart = Double.valueOf(mapObj.get("autostart").toString());`

Comment: Converting a Number to String and back is very inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you only need one cast.

```
double autostart = (Double) mapObj.get("autostart");
```

Comment: That's giving me a "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer" runtime exception.

Comment: Well, you need a double then!

Comment: @justkevin Your "autostart" variable is of type double. I updated the code.

Comment: The "autostart" value represents an integer. Mongo doesn't have an integer type, just numbers.

Comment: @Justkevin not mongo, but JSON.